# Erase and Install a fresh copy of Ubuntu to start over

Tags: reset

I bought this hp mini off an old friend. well it has been running for quiet a while and it seems like since 2001 (that'as the recent modified dates seen on the files). This is my first laptop with Ubuntu and it seems I've made a mess with the system since then. I was just wondering if I could erase and start over with a fresh copy since is no such option to restore to factory command similar to Windows. I recently upgraded it, even-though I had no idea what I was doing and it changed from 10.04 to 12.04. But the power cord came out, and battery died while I was asleep. Regardless, I should say that the upgrade went half. Nevertheless, I logged-in finally, but now all kinds of errors pops-up as I have duplicate things going on. All I wanted is to start from scratch with fresh install. How can I achieve this??

Comment: Follow the link given by @Mitch.. That's a good start for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a program to install Ubuntu from a Linux system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991875/)

Answer (score 0):

Christina,  At least your are trying.  I will give you my best answer for now, since I don't know exactly what you are working with.  For starters, do you have a DVD player or are you using only usb? Reference: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If you are using a DVD, you will want to download the iso image for your chip, (32bit or 64bit). If you can still use the operating system, burn the ISO and run the disk.  If you are using usb, you will have to create a bootable usb device. Reference: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

You will have to make adjustments in your bios, select your boot device.  Once you get the correct device selected to boot, you will be able to follow the directions to install our software. When you get to the part that ask you how you want to install it, choose erase and use the entire disk.

Hopes this helps you.

Jim

Comment: that is  the problem currently I don't have a extra usb and the mini no dvd