# Boot files from ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

I could able to boot Ubuntu from USB but I don't know how to boot files from Ubuntu. Can anyone give some suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Regards
Yojitha E

Comment: Is this what you're asking about [Is there a program to install Ubuntu from a Linux system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991875/is-there-a-program-to-install-ubuntu-from-a-linux-system)?