# Where are netboot files for hirsute 21.04?

Tags: pxe

I am searching for netboot files for Hirsute Hippo 21.04, ie *linux* and *initrd.gz*

The usual repo path that worked for 20.04 LTS (
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/) don't work for Hirsute Hippo.

Where I can find those files ?

Comment: The netboot installer was deprecated in 20.04 (that's why it was in *legacy-images*), and has since been discontinued. It was a byproduct of a workflow that has changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the MinimalCd / mini.iso for Groovy Gorilla?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291913/where-is-the-minimalcd-mini-iso-for-groovy-gorilla)

Comment: Deprecation of mini.iso is absolutely wrong decision. Many users [still need it](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/poll-about-possible-netboot-mini-iso-revival-in-future-ubuntu-releases/19457). So such users will [switch to Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall) or use [20.04 LTS mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/) as starting point, then upgrade it to latest release.

Answer (score 0):

The netboot installer has been discontinued. Files vmlinuz and initrd for pxe may be copied from standard installation image ( they are in the directory /casper )