# Is it possible to have linux kernel >5.4 in the netboot mini.iso of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel, updates, iso

I see that latest netboot [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) still [has](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/udeb.list) kernel version 5.4.0-42 which is quiet old.

Is it possible to have the same netboot mini.iso with newer kernel, for example HWE 5.13?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it possible by building our own mini.iso from sources. The build process should be run inside Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on real hardware, VM or in Docker with enabled `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Exact list of commands is the following.

```
# sudo sed -i 's/# deb-src/deb-src/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install fakeroot
sudo apt-get build-dep debian-installer

cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source debian-installer
cd debian-installer-20101020ubuntu614.3
cd build

# change kernel version only for amd64 which we are currently running
sed -i "s/BASEVERSION = 5.4.0-42/BASEVERSION = 5.13.0-28/g" config/amd64.cfg

make reallyclean
fakeroot make build_netboot
```

The resulting ISO will be available on the `dest/netboot/mini.iso` path, it will use 5.13 HWE kernel.
So it will compatible with wider spectrum of hardware on first boot time.

**Important**: to install HWE kernel 5.13 into target system one should boot using *Advanced Options* → *Expert Install*, follow wizard as usual and then on the *Install the base system* screen select *`linux-generic-hwe-20.04`* kernel to install

[image: d-i, expert install, select linux-generic-hwe-20.04 to install]

then proceed with GRUB installation and so on.

Later in spring this system may be upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) using release upgrade procedure.

---

Latest HWE kernel version may be determined from:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/linux-hwe-5.13
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/debian-installer/

General documentation about Debian installer is here:

- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Build

Comment: +1: Thanks for boiling down all that complexity into a simple, easy-to-follow set of instructions.

Comment: THANK YOU! Awesome Instructions, will be trying this out sometime this week.