# How to uninstall older version (15.04) of Ubuntu and install newer(18.04)

Tags: boot

I have installed  Ubuntu version 15.04  on my laptop which already had windows 10 by partitioning the disk 
I have not yet stored any files in Ubuntu but found the installation process incomplete and is incompatible to install some softwares 
So I need to install Ubuntu version (18.04) which is downloaded and files are extracted into bootable pen drive
Pls help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and [Erase and Install a fresh copy of Ubuntu to start over](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345923/erase-and-install-a-fresh-copy-of-ubuntu-to-start-over)

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 (2015.April release) reached EOL Jan-2016 (15.04 + 9 months = 16.01) as it wasn't a LTS or long-term-support release, which has five years of supported life.  To install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (2018.April release), just install it over your 15.04 [using the whatever partitioning you created for 15.04].

Comment: Create a pendrive using UNetbootin or Rufus. Use that pendrive to install to the internal drive's existing Ubuntu partition(s) using "Something else". If you have anything on the existing Ubuntu's home directory worth saving, it can be saved and reused.